# Orienting Variables Matrix

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

[image]

For the system of equations above, if I were to use matrices to solve for each of the variables, how is the variables matrix ordered? If all the variables in the equations are aligned vertically (as they already are), if I look at one of the equations, do the variables from the left to right correspond to the variables matrix's up and down? In other words, would the variables matrix then be ordered as such: the top variable is z, the middle variable is x, and the bottom variable is y? What is the general rule for orienting the variable matrix, because I can't seem to find one online?

Comment: Do it however you want.  There is no requirement that they be in a canonical order.  If you want it to be $z,x,y$ from left-to-right, then the result will be read as $z,x,y$ from top to down.  If you want it to be $x,y,z$ from left-to-right then the result will be read as $x,y,z$ from top to down.  You will get the same answer either way.  The point is to understand what it is you are doing and how to interpret the result and be consistent with how you interpret things within a problem.

Comment: @54284User Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

Usually we choose the alphabetical order $x,y,z$ but of course we can also use any others order and in particular $z,x,y$.

In the latter case the matrix form will be

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&-1\\-1&2&1\\-3&-1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}z\\x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\7\end{bmatrix}$$

which is completely equivalent to

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2\\2&1&-1\\-1&2&-3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\7\end{bmatrix}$$